# Find likely processes based on snapshot in time

Tags: command-line, text-processing

### Introduction

I'm trying to capture what process(es) started over a limited time period.

I've created a script (`ps-suspects.sh`) where:

- I run `ps-suspects.sh` from the terminal.
- I start up and close an application, let's say the Desktop Calculator.
- I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to end `ps-suspects.sh`
- I want to know what the process name for the Calculator is
- I don't want a listing all the other process names running the whole period of the snapshot.

### The problem

I have a snippet of code that needs fine-tuning:

```
$ sort -k15 ~/pid.log | uniq -f14 -c
```

Here is what it produces:

```
$ head ~/pid.tmp
  1 /mnt/e/bin/ps-suspects.sh Possible suspects causing problems
 63 1 S root       127     2  0  60 -20 -     0 -      Sep08 ?        00:00:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
 63 1 S root        75     2  0  60 -20 -     0 -      Sep08 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
 63 1 S root       447     2  0  60 -20 -     0 -      Sep08 ?        00:00:00 [ath10k_aux_wq]
 63 1 S root       446     2  0  60 -20 -     0 -      Sep08 ?        00:00:00 [ath10k_wq]
 63 1 S avahi      922   910  0  80   0 - 11195 -      Sep08 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
 63 4 S avahi      910     1  0  80   0 - 11228 -      Sep08 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: running [alien.local]
126 0 S rick      2902  2867  0  80   0 -  7409 wait_w Sep08 pts/18   00:00:00 bash
 63 0 S rick     25894  5775  0  80   0 -  4908 wait   10:43 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash /mnt/e/bin/ps-suspects.sh
 63 0 S root       980   976  0  80   0 -  4921 -      Sep08 ?        00:00:01 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/display-auto-brightness
```

I want to eliminate all the lines that occur `63` or more times.

### Desired Output

```
$ ps-suspects.sh
20 times / second ps -elf is captured to /home/rick/pid.log

Type Ctrl+C when done capturing

~/pid.log is sorted and uniq counted on column 15
which is full path and program name.

Then all matches with same unique count (the headings)
are stripped and only new processes started are printed.

This function can help you trace down what processes are
causing you grief for lid close events, hot plugging, etc.
^C 
wc of ~/pid.log :   17288  343162 2717102 /home/rick/pid.log

HighCnt: 63
      1 /mnt/e/bin/ps-suspects.sh Possible suspects causing problems
     26 0 R rick     25976  2051  0  80   0 - 120676 -     10:43 ?        00:00:00 gnome-calculator
     62 0 S root     22561   980  0  80   0 -  3589 -      10:42 ?        00:00:00 sleep 60
```

### Question

In this example `63` will appear on 90%-99% of the lines in column 1 and those lines need to be removed. All occurrences of `126`could also be removed. So anything **the most occurring and greater** can be removed.

Can someone come up with the missing `awk` and/or `uniq` and/or `grep` to finish the task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python to the rescue:

```bsh
python3 -c 'import sys,collections;l=[(int(L.split(None,1)[0]),L)for L in sys.stdin.readlines()];m=collections.Counter(x[0]for x in l).most_common(1)[0][0];print(*[x[1]for x in l if x[0]<m],sep="",end="")'
```

Alternative, uncompressed version for use as script file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import collections

# read lines from stdin (with trailing \n) and extract the number in their first column
items = [(int(line.split(None, 1)[0]), line) for line in sys.stdin]
# find the most common number from the first column
most_common = collections.Counter(item[0] for item in items).most_common()[0][0]
# print input lines in order, but only those with their number lower than the most common
print(*[item[1] for item in items if item[0] < most_common], sep="", end="")
```

The only assumption this script makes about its input, which is expected to be piped into stdin, is that each line has a valid integer number in its first whitespace-separated column. The lines are not required to be sorted in any form.

---

**Note:** If there are multiple different most common numbers in the first column with the same count, which of those two gets picked is arbitrary, but should be constant for the same input. In case this is undesired, you'd have to replace the line finding the most common value with something like this instead, to find the highest most common value:

```py
most_common = sorted(collections.Counter(item[0] for item in items).most_common(),
                     key=lambda x:x[::-1])[-1][0]
```

---

Example input:

```
1 foo
3 bar
2 baz
3 apple
3 banana
2 cherry
4 beep
```

Example output:

```
1 foo
2 baz
2 cherry
```

Comment: The test data file and sample output certainly proves it's working. I've added the whole bash script to the question. I notice your shebang says Python 3 but couldn't this code work with any Python version? Can a Python interpreter be inserted in-line within the bash interpreter / gnome-terminal shell? Maybe some sort of << EOF thingy? Would it make more sense to do the whole thing in Python and avoid hybrid programming?

Comment: You could pipe it like `sort ... | uniq ... | python3 -c '...'`, sure. Whether you want to port the rest of your script to Python, have two script files, or this inline Python command, it's up to you. Regarding Python 2, the print syntax I used is not backwards compatible, but it could be adapted if necessary.

Comment: Piping to Python3 reduces maintenance efforts I think. As far as Python 2 I haven't use it nor Python 3. I've only read problems here with people having different versions of 2.7 and 3.6 installed at the same time or something like that. My system shows: `$ apt list | grep -i python3 | wc -l` =  `1523` and `$ apt list | grep -i python2 | wc -l` = `19`. So I guess I'm safe. I'll wait 24 hours to see if any histogram experts have 'awk' or other solutions before accepting your answer :)

Comment: Accepting answer now as I found an `awk` solution from four different Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow answers. As it turns out the process reseting my external monitors was already running anyway so I'll have to search on which process had higher CPU% over the 6 to 10 seconds. *shrugs* Thank you for teaching me a bit about Python. I'm still looking forward to my first project :)

Comment: I always upvote a question where the OP accepted my answer because it means: it's a good question and a good answer **>:-)**

Answer (score 3):

### `awk` to the rescue

After `sort` and `uniq` have done their job, I used `awk` to finish the project. Byte's accepted answer remains as he was the first to answer and provided excellent insights into using Python. In the end though I hobbled together 3 or 4 different **Stack Exchange** Questions & Answers to arrive at a working solution.

Here is the full script for those who are interested:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo 20 times / second ps -elf is captured to ~/pid.log
echo
echo "Type Ctrl+C when done capturing"
echo
echo "~/pid.log is sorted and uniq counted on column 15"
echo "which is full path and program name."
echo
echo "Then all matches with same unique count (the headings)"
echo "are stripped and only new processes started are printed."
echo
echo "This function can help you trace down what processes are"
echo "causing you grief for lid close events, hot plugging, etc."

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
    echo " "
    printf "wc of ~/pid.log : " 
    wc ~/pid.log
    echo
    # Tally occurances of same Command Name always running
    sort -k15 ~/pid.log | uniq -f14 -c > ~/pid.tmp
    # What is the most frequent occurance?
    <~/pid.tmp awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c > ~/pid.wrk
    HighCnt=$(awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print want} '\
        ~/pid.wrk)
    echo HighCnt: $HighCnt
    # Exclude all processes => highest count
    awk '($1 < var) ' var="$HighCnt" ~/pid.tmp
    rm ~/pid.wrk ~/pid.tmp ~/pid.log
    
    exit 0
}

echo "$0 Possible suspects causing problems" > ~/pid.log

while true ; do

    ps -elf >> ~/pid.log
    sleep .05 # 20 samples / second
    
done
```

### Missing pieces

This is the code I added to make it work.

```bash
# What is the most frequent occurance?
<~/pid.tmp awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c > ~/pid.wrk
HighCnt=$(awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print want} '\
    ~/pid.wrk)
echo HighCnt: $HighCnt
# Exclude all processes => highest count
awk '($1 < var) ' var="$HighCnt" ~/pid.tmp
```

---

#### Sample Output

The `gnome-calculator` PID shows up as desired. There is an extra line `sleep 60` which is not wanted but occurs because a daemon woke up and slept again during the test period.

```bash
$ ps-suspects.sh
10 times / second ps -elf is captured to /home/rick/pid.log

Type Ctrl+C when done capturing

~/pid.log is sorted and uniq counted on column 15
which is full path and program name.

Then all matches with same unique count (the headings)
are stripped and only new processes started are printed.

This function can help you trace down what processes are
causing you grief for lid close events, hot plugging, etc.
^C 
wc of ~/pid.log :   17288  343162 2717102 /home/rick/pid.log

HighCnt: 63
      1 /mnt/e/bin/ps-suspects.sh Possible suspects causing problems
     26 0 R rick     25976  2051  0  80   0 - 120676 -     10:43 ?        00:00:00 gnome-calculator
     62 0 S root     22561   980  0  80   0 -  3589 -      10:42 ?        00:00:00 sleep 60
```