# How to determine what command is being run from a menu icon?

Tags: command-line, gnome, icons

I sometimes run into an issue where I try to run an app from the GNOME menu and nothing happens - the app name appears in the upper left and the spinny cursor comes up for a bit, but the application never launches.

I want to try to troubleshoot what is happening by running the same command, whatever it is, from the command line, to see what the output is.  But I don't know what command is being run.  If I right click on the icon in the menu, I see a "Show Details" option. But it doesn't work the way I expect - it takes me to the software center, which sometimes isn't even right because it's not there.  But in no case does it actually give me a clue as to what the command line is that it is invoking.

Where can I find this information?

update: I found a related question which got me the information - I found that "menulibre" was already installed by default.  It didn't solve my initial problem though, because the command ran find from the command line.

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072170/find-likely-processes-based-on-snapshot-in-time

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It looks like they are running `ps` 20 times/second.  I'm not sure the command being run is sticking around long enough to even show up in ps at that rate.

Comment: the one used to lock this q is more interesting: we still all have a menu editor that holds the info you need.

Comment: FYI that was my Q&A and `sleep(.05)` can be changed to `sleep(.01)`  for 100 times per second.